# Creating variables within Android Services

Tags: android, android-service

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I could not find an answer on stackoverflow or elsewhere.

What is the proper convention for declaring variables within an Android Service? If I declare any variables outside of the normal methods in a Service (onCreate, etc.) my App crashes as soon as the Service is started.

Here's what I mean by declaring variables outside of the normal methods:

```
public class MyService extends Service 
{

    final ClipboardManager clippy = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        ...
    }

...
}
```

The above crashes. However if I declare the my variables inside a method, the Service does not crash.

Once again, I apologize if this has been covered elsewhere, and thanks in advance.

Comment: downvoter for the sake of god,please don't downvote...he is apologizing upto hell;you cruel.

Comment: It's okay, I think my question was too simple for stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm an idiot obviously. But in case anyone else has the same question here's the answer.

Convention (from what I can tell by reading other open source android applications) is to declare but not initialize variables outside of the methods and the initialize them later as needed.

I can see why no one answered this; it's more of a basic programming question than an Android question.